# How to pass special characters through sed

Tags: bash, sed, special-characters

I want to pass this command in my script:
`sed -n -e "/Next</a></p>/,/Next</a></p>/ p" file.txt`
This command (should) extract all text between the two matched patterns, which are both `Next</a></p>` in my case. However when I run my script I keep getting errors. I've tried:
`sed -n -e "/Next\<\/a\>\<\/p\>/,/Next<\/a\>\<\/p>/ p" file.txt` with no luck.

I believe the generic pattern for this command is this:
`sed -n -e "/pattern1/,/pattern2/ p" file.txt`
I can't get it working for `Next</a></p>` though and I'm guessing it has something to do with the special characters I am encasing. Is there any way to pass `Next</a></p>` in the `sed` command? Thanks in advance guys! This community is awesome!

Comment: The command you posted, even when corrected, will not extract text between the two matched patterns. Tell us what you're really trying to do with some sample input and expected output and we can put you on the right path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use <kbd>/</kbd> as a regular expression delimiter. Using a different character will make quoting issues slightly easier. The syntax is

`\cregexc`

where `c` can be any character (other than <kbd>\</kbd>) that you don't use in the regex. In this case, <kbd>:</kbd> might be a good choice:

```
sed -n -e '\:Next</a></p>:,\:Next</a></p>: p' file.txt
```

Note that I changed <kbd>"</kbd> to <kbd>'</kbd> because inside double quotes, <kbd>\</kbd> will be interpreted by bash as an escape character, whereas inside single quotes <kbd>\</kbd> is just treated as a regular character. Consequently, you could have written the version with escaped slashes like this:

```
sed -n -e '/Next<\/a><\/p>/,/Next<\/a><\/p>/ p' file.txt
```

but I think the version with colons is (slightly) easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the forward slashes inside the regular expressions with a `\`, since the forward slashes serve as delimiters for the regexes

```
sed -n -e '/Next<\/a><\/p>/,/Next<\/a><\/p>/p' file.txt
```